# How to develop VSPackages in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage, visual-studio-templates

I have installed `Visual Studio 2015 RC SDK` on my machine.
I don't have `Visual Studio Package` template when creating a new project. This is the screen shot of `Visual Studio 2015 RC`

[image]

As you can see no templates for `Visual Studio Package`.

This is the screen shot of my `Visual Studio 2013`:

[image]

**Question**

How to develop `VSPackages` in `Visual Studio 2015 RC`?

**NOTE**

I already have `Visual Studio 2015 RC SDK` installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS 2015, you start with a VSIX project, and then add Items, like for example a VSPackage - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/05/29/extending-visual-studio-2015.aspx